# Set the Working Folder of `.app` Created by Apple Script

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, command-line, bash

I have a simple Shell File `.sh` which copies files form the PWD to a destination folder.
This is basically Hand Made installer of a program.
I want to create an APP from it.

The idea is to have the following structure of the files at the user:

```
- MyApp
    - SourceFiles/
    - MyInstaller.app
```

Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Copying

cp -r './SourceFiles/.' '/DestFolder/SourceFiles/'

exit 0
```

I created an Apple Script (`MyInstaller.scpt`) file which looks:

```
tell me to activate

display dialog "Run My Installer?" buttons {"Run", "Cancel"} default button 1

if the button returned of the result is "Run" then
    do shell script "cp -r './SourceFiles/.' '/DestFolder/SourceFiles/' & exit 0;" with administrator privileges

    display dialog "Finished Successfully!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1

end if
```

I compile it with `osacompile -o MyInstaller.app MyInstaller.scpt`.

Then I try to run `MyInstaller.app` it doesn't work.
Though if I run the `sh` Shell Script form the same location it works.

I had a feeling it is related to the `PWD` of the APP when it runs.
So I did the following trick, I compiled an `.APP` from the following Apple Script:

```
do shell script "pwd > ~/Temp.txt & exit 0;"
```

Then I saw at `Temp.txt` that the `PWD` is `/` (Namely the Root).
Indeed if I copy `SourceFiles/` to the root and run the APP it copes the files correctly.

Is there a way to make the APP of the AppleScript to run relative to the location of the compiled `APP`?

Answer (score 3):

One way to handle this is to set a *variable*, e.g. `myPath`, and build out from there.

```AppleScript
set myPath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)
```

The `myPath` *variable* will be returned in the form of:

```
/path/to/AppName.app/
```

You can then concatenate  `myPath` and addition *path segments* and *filename* as needed.

Note that when using this in a `do shell script` *command*, use `quoted form of` to allow for *spaces* in the *path filename*.

---

Have a look at the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1) and more specifically: [path to (application)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW18)

> **path to (application)**
>
> Returns the location of the specified application.
>
> ...
>
> me
>
> The script itself. For script
>   applications, this is the same as current application, but for script
>   documents, it is the location of the document.

Comment: But I don't know the path of the APP. So what to put in `path to me as text`?

Comment: @Royi, Use exactly what I wrote!

Comment: Wow. OK, I will give it a try.

Comment: @Royi, I've added some links and a partial quote; however, please take the time to read the documentation.

Comment: OK, Your answer with this - [Technical Note TN2065 - `do shell script` in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html) gave me the picture. Thank You.

Comment: I encountered some other problem I'd be happy to your advise. The `app` should be run from a `DMG`. It seems that on the `DMG` the path returned to the variable `myPath` doesn't work. Any idea on that?

Comment: @Royi, It works for me from a DMG; however, without seeing your explicit and specific code, there is no way for me to troubleshoot your code.

Comment: OK, I pasted the code in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359118. It seems I have issues in case `myPath` contains spaces.