# Running Compiled AppleScript from DMG Doesn't Work

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, bash, dmg

As a follow up for my previous question ([Set the Working Folder of `.app` Created by Apple Script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359016)) I have the following problem.

I have an AppleScript which is Poor man's Installer:

```
tell me to activate

set appPath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)

set folderName to "'MyFolderName'"

set copyFolder to "cp -r " & appPath & folderName & "'/.' '/Library/Application Support/'" & folderName & "'/' & "

set exitScript to "exit 0;"

display dialog "Run Installer?" buttons {"Run", "Cancel"} default button 1

if the button returned of the result is "Run" then
    do shell script copyFolder & exitScript with administrator privileges

    display dialog "Finished Successfully!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1

end if
```

So the script above is compiled into `Installer.app`.
Inside it I put the folder `MyFolderName` which contains all the sources.

I create a a DMG with the title (Also the Path) `My Project`.
I run `Install.app` from the installer and it doesn't work.
I run the `Installer.app` from Desktop (Or any other place on HD) and it works.

I also changed the DMG title to have no spaces `MyProject` and it works.

So something in the parsing of `appPath` into the Script doesn't work if it contains spaces.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [my answer to your other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359016/set-the-working-folder-of-app-created-by-apple-script/359035#359035):

> Note that when using this in a `do shell script` *command*, use `quoted form of` to allow for *spaces* in the *path filename*.

Otherwise you'd need to escape spaces with a backslash `\`, and that can get messy.

---

Example: `quoted form of appPath`

You might want to do the concatenation separately and then pass it to the *command*.

Comment: So I need to do: `set myPath to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me as text)`?

Comment: @Royi, You can use `quoted form of` in may different ways, and yes `set appPath to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me as text)` or  as shown in the example of my answer `quoted form of appPath`.

Comment: OK, I will give it a try and report. Thank you for your assistance.